# Problems with DataTables jQuery library i need to get sum of column after filtering

Tags: datatables, filtering

I have table with custom filter, after I use it, I want to get sum of one field with this:

```
$('#articlesTable').dataTable()._('td:nth-child(12)', {"filter": "applied"})
```

But i get array with elements only form first page in my table.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in:

```
"bDeferRender": true,
```

When i use it i got wrong results! Theoretically, disabling "bDeferRender" will affect on performance. In my case i have about 3000 - 6000 rows and it's ok!